# How to compare two Queue<int>?

Tags: c#, sorting, queue

My simplified c# code is below. I have a list of Queues that have costs inside of them. I want the queue with the lowest cost to be the first element of the list.

The order inside the Queues is important. I cannot reorder them.

I want to modify my code so when x.Peek() = y.Peek(), compare the 2nd values in each Queue.

```
Declare Queue
List<Queue<int>> ListofQueues;
.....
// Perform Sort
ListofQueues.Sort((x, y) => x.Peek().CompareTo(y.Peek()));
ListofQueues[0].Dequeue();
```

Comment: Surely the queue with the lowest cost depends on the sum of its elements?

Comment: Total cost wouldn't work for queues of different size.

The order that I Dequeue() is important to me. 
At every step I want to make sure I have the lowest cost per dequenue()

Comment: Why would the second value in each queue represent the lowest cost of the queue? That doesn't make sense. To quote Caius above "Surely the queue with the lowest cost depends on the sum of its elements?". Besides, you can't Peek() at the second element. You'd have to create a new class that inherits from Queue and implement your own SuperPeek() method, or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Queue<int>> ListofQueues = new List<Queue<int>>();
ListofQueues.Sort((x, y) => x.ToList()[2].CompareTo(y.ToList()[2]));
ListofQueues[0].Dequeue();
```